# Question regarding Panchakatcham and Madisar dressing

Tags: dress

In Southern India, the dress code of men wearing panchakatcham and women wearing madisar saree is known quite well and only married men and women are allowed to wear this. Though this was the only dress code to be worn 24x7, but nowadays it is followed only during praying and few other occasions although there are some orthodox couples who still wear this all the time.

While this is the dress code for married people in the south, the North Indians seems to have no restrictions as such. Sri Bala Krishna himself is an example.

[image]

Image source:http://readymademadisar.com/kids.html (disclaimer: I am neither associated nor promoting, but saw this cute kid and considered him as Krishna himself)

For those who do not know, Panchakatcham means 5 insertions - when translated crudely and is explained well in [this site](http://www.wikihow.com/Wear-a-Pancha-Kachcham).

My questions are:

1. What pramaanavatchanam (authentic quote/instruction) talks about this dress code for men and women? In other words what are the references of this dress code in Smritis or Shruti texts?
2. While we see the Lord in many temples and photos wearing this panchakatcham, it is very rare (or non existent) to see the Goddess in Madisar. Why is this so?

Comment: 1. North India underwent a lot of hardship via foreign, Non Hindu invasions for centuries. Their culture is also therefore  heavily influenced by the non Hindu cultures. Probably the reason for forsaking the kacha style clothes. 2. Goddess always wears her saree in kacha fashion. I've never seen a picture that depicts otherwise.

Comment: @moonstar2001 This is not to debate, but the villagers of Northern India, wear panchakatcham kind of dhoti.

Comment: Northern states also have a nauvari tradition -- maheshwari and chanderis (madhyapradesh), the paithani (Maharashtra) and even Banarasi (kashi had links to the present day madhyapradesh, chattisgarh and Maharashtra) weaves are still made in nauvaris (nine yards) for families in these areas. So I suspect the tradition of such madisar-like saree drapes or drapes with kaccham exists more than just the southern states that wear them more frequently than is seen elsewhere.